Why is Remmina correctly forwarding keyboard layout but not control key combinations?
I recently found how to make Remmina forward my Dvorak keyboard layout, but for some reason control-key combinations are not forwarded and the remote machine mapping is being used instead. That is quite annoying when using Bash@putty with no ability to access Bash reverse-i-search shortcut (Ctrl+R).
How are we supposed to make Remmina also forward Ctrl+KEY?

